# On reference and resource requests

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

There are at least two tags that are related to requests: [reference-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and [resource-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request). The current description of the former is

> Use this tag when requesting examples of research or links to papers. For example, "What paper is a good place to start in the field of X?" or "What are good examples of Y in research?"

while the description of the latter is

> Use for questions about resources helpful in AI endeavors. This can include training data. (May also be used in conjunction with "software-evaluation" if the request involves software as opposed to data.)

*Shouldn't we change the description and scope of [reference-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) to include all types of references (e.g. books, thesis, etc)?* I think so.

The description of the second tag is not very clear. *Any suggestions to clarify it?*

It seems to me that these tags have an overlapping scope. For example, this question [What is the predicted timeline for driverless metros worldwide?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/15634/2444) could apparently be tagged with both. *What do you think?*

*Also, are these tags consistent with the on-topic page?*

Answer (score 1):

My main thought is that we've been seeing requests for data sets to use in training, and these would represent resource requests as opposed to reference requests.

Similarly for people looking for published code to utilize (GitHub as a resource.)

Comment: I am not saying that [tag:resource-request] should necessarily be merged with [tag:reference-request], but I think we should clarify the description of these tags.